# Pop up Javascript alert when PHP code starts to run and alert when finished execution

Tags: javascript, php, json, codeigniter

I have a php controller that invokes according to a JavaScript click function. I want to pop up a JavaScript alert box when this code starts to run and alert again after finish execution. How to achieve this inside the php controller

example:

```
<?php
  class admin_rentals extends base_admin {
     function update_user_verification_status() {

        // should pop up the alert box
        // executes the code
        // alert when execution finished
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you using ajax to invoke the controller?

Comment: The answer is you cannot do it from your controller. Because javascript is client side and php is server side. You need to learn the difference

Comment: @SubashSelvaraj, yes , I would like to catch a jason encode data inside the success function

Comment: @웃웃웃웃웃: I know the difference, but when problem came in we have to work-out on that to get a solution. can you read the question again. controller spawn by a ajax request,I was a core java developer and new to PHP

Comment: You can check my updated answer @BRjava

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it from your controller. You can do it from your java script if that function is executed by ajax.Something like this

```
alert('Execution started');
$.ajax({
url : 'path/to/your/function',
type: 'post',
  success: function(res){
    alert('Execution completed');
  }
});
```

PHP

```
class admin_rentals extends base_admin {
     function update_user_verification_status() {
           $arrRet = array('message'=>'This is a json');
           echo json_encode($arrRet);
        }
}
```

Comment: Yes, This is fine, yet I want to know how to send a jason encoded data to this success function from php controller, can you post example

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
  class admin_rentals extends base_admin {
     function update_user_verification_status() {

        // should pop up the alert box
        echo "<script language=\"javascript\">alert('start execution');</script>";
        // executes the code
        // alert when execution finished
        echo "<script language=\"javascript\">alert('execution finished');</script>";
        }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the server finishes responding to your request is approximately when the PHP code finishes.

Assuming you are making an AJAX call, wait until the call has returned and then you may print out an `alert` message.